# Change one select based on the value of another with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html-select

I need one `<select>` dropdown to change based on another. Here is what I have so far, which is not working.

**HTML**

```
<html>
<head>
...
</head>
<body>      
    <form>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Dropdown Menu 1</td>
                <td>Dropdown Menu 2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <select id="ddl1" onchange="changeDropdown(this,document.getElementById('ddl2'))">
                        <option value=""><!---------></option>
                        <option value="Colors">Colors</option>
                        <option value="Shapes">Shapes</option>
                        <option value="Sounds">Sounds</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select id="ddl2">
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script>
    function changeDropdown(ddl1,ddl2) {
        var colors = new Array('Black', 'Brown', 'Blue');
        var shapes = new Array('Triangle', 'Square', 'Circle');
        var sounds = new Array('Loud', 'Soft');

        switch (ddl1.value) {
            case 'Colors':
                for (i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
                    createOptions(ddl2, colors[i], colors[i]);
                }
                break;
            default:
                ddl2.options.length = 0;
                break;
        }
    }
    function createOptions(ddl,text,value) {
        var opt = document.createElement('option');
        opt.value = value;
        opt.text = text;
        ddl.option.add(opt);
    }
</script>
```

This needs to be in Javascript. I know that people usually advice jQuery for stuff like this, but this needs to be Javascript.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

-Anthony

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
opt.option.add(opt);
```

Do:

```
ddl.appendChild(opt);
```

Comment: Thanks. This does not work though. Edit: ha. I just saw this was you. Thanks though.

Comment: I don't see how that possible.  I copied all the code above and just changed that line and I got options (only with Color in the first menu).  Any errors in the console? ddl.add(opt); does work on my end too.  But I know for a fact that the object you are targeting should be ddl, not opt.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
function createOptions(ddl,text,value) {
    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.setAttribute("value", value);
    opt.innerHTML=text;
    ddl.appendChild(opt);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 opt.option.add(opt);
```

Seems like you're adding the option to itself.

Comment: Changed to `ddl.option.add(opt)`. It still doesn't work. Thanks for catching that, though.

Comment: Try to replace option to options.

Comment: It works, check here: http://jsbin.com/dekopeyuso/1/edit?html,js,output But only if you select Colors, since that's the only defined case except default.

Comment: I copied your code into my file and it works. There is something different; have to find out what exactly.